# Collection Binding on CollectionViewSource Source Property

Tags: wpf, binding, wpfdatagrid, collectionviewsource

I've a `CollectionViewSource` as `ItemsSource` of my `DataGrid`. In `Window.Resources` I have this definition:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="ItemsPoolCollectionView"  
     Source="{Binding Path=MyObservableCollection, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

now, I would like to produce the same definition from code, so I've done this:

```
Dim _cvs as CollectionViewSource = New CollectionViewSource
Dim bindSource = New Binding() With {
        .Path = New PropertyPath("MyObservableCollection"),
        .Mode = BindingMode.OneWay }
_cvs.SetValue(CollectionViewSource.SourceProperty, bindSource)
```

but I've this error on the last statement:

> ```
> 'System.Windows.Data.Binding' is not a valid value for property 'Source'
> ```

What's wrong? How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solve! ...in this way:

```
      Dim _cvs as CollectionViewSource = New CollectionViewSource
      Dim bindSource = New Binding() With {
              .Source = Me.DataContext
              .Path = New PropertyPath("MyObservableCollection"),
              .Mode = BindingMode.OneWay }
      BindingOperations.SetBinding(cvs, CollectionViewSource.SourceProperty, bindSource)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to bind a `CollectionViewSource` in order to make it "bind" automatically; just set the value of the Source property directly:

```
Dim _cvs as CollectionViewSource = New CollectionViewSource
_cvs.Source = Me.MyObservableCollection
```

(sorry for my rusty VB.net)

For more info, see the following forum post:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/f44df11b-dfa8-4173-bbc8-051875fce4cc

Comment: I try and it works...but if I change "MyObservebleCollection" on datacontext (clear, add or remove items) the collectionviewsource seems lost the source association.